# Java Hibernate Add query

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g

I am facing a problem while trying to persist the existing stock in a preproduction environment.
What I am trying to do is actually to loop on a text file and insert substrings from that file into the database.

Here is the class that I execute :

public class RepriseStock { 
        private static Session session;

```
    public RepriseStock() { 
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession(); 
            session.beginTransaction(); 
    } 

    public static int insererPartenaires(String sCurrentLine, int i) { 
            String sql = "INSERT INTO PARTENAIRE(ID," 
                            + "MVTSOC," 
                            + " MVTAGR, " 
                            + "MVTNOMSOC," 
                            + "MVTCPTTMAG," 
                            + "DATEAGREMENT," 
                            + "MVTCHAINE," 
                            + "MVTRGPT," 
                            + "MVTUNION," 
                            + "MVTNOMMAG," 
                            + "MVTTELSOC," 
                            + "MVTADRMAG," 
                            + "MVTVILMAG," 
                            + "MVTMAIL," 
                            + "MVTSITU)" 
                            + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; 

            Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql); 

            query.setInteger(0, i); 

            query.setInteger(1, Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine.substring(0, 3))); 
            query.setInteger(2, Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine.substring(3, 10))); 
            query.setString(3, sCurrentLine.substring(10, 34)); 
            query.setInteger(4, Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine.substring(48, 53))); 

            query.setString(5, sCurrentLine.substring(77, 83)); 

            query.setInteger(6, Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine.substring(86, 90))); 
            query.setInteger(7, Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine.substring(90, 94))); 
            // union 
            query.setInteger(8, Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine.substring(94, 98))); 
            // enseigne 30 
            query.setString(9, sCurrentLine.substring(248, 278)); 
            // tel 
            query.setString(10, sCurrentLine.substring(278, 293)); 
            // adresse 
            query.setString(11, sCurrentLine.substring(293, 323)); 
            // ville 
            query.setString(12, sCurrentLine.substring(323, 348)); 
            // mail 

            query.setString(13, sCurrentLine.substring(398, 448)); 
            // situ 
            query.setString(14, sCurrentLine.substring(449, 452)); 

            return query.executeUpdate(); 

    } 

    /** 
     * @param args 
     */ 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
            // TODO Module de remplacement de méthode auto-généré 

            BufferedReader br = null; 
            RepriseStock rs = new RepriseStock(); 

            try { 

                    String sCurrentLine; 

                    br = new BufferedReader( 
                                    new FileReader( 
                                                    "C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\test\\reprise de stock\\nouveauFichierPREPROD.dat")); 
                    int i = 0; 
                    sCurrentLine = br.readLine(); 
                    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) { 
                            i++; 

                            RepriseStock.insererPartenaires(sCurrentLine, i); 

                            System.out.println("Nombre de fois : " + i); 

                    } 

                    System.out.println("total (" + i + " )"); 
            } catch (IOException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
            } finally { 
                    try { 
                            if (br != null) 
                                    br.close(); 
                    } catch (IOException ex) { 
                            ex.printStackTrace(); 
                    } 
            } 

    }
```

}

After the script is executed, i have the total of loops is 1022 times. But the data is not persisted into oracle table (Partenaire)

My log doesn't display any error.

Do you see the issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're not committing the transaction.

If you want each update to be a separate transaction, try moving `session.beginTransaction();` to the beginning of the `insererPartenaires` method and capturing the `Transaction` object returned from that statement in a variable. Then, after each update, make sure to call `commit()` on the `Transaction` object.

If you want all of the updates to be the same transaction, move the `beginTransaction()` and `commit()` methods to surround the while loop in the main method.

---

Also just note that you're unnecessarily mixing static and non-static here. Try changing `public static int insererPartenaires(String sCurrentLine, int i)` to `public int insererPartenaires(String sCurrentLine, int i)`. Then just use the instantiated `RepriseStock` object to call the method instead of invoking it statically.

You'll also need to change `private static Session session` to be `private Session session`